# Linq statement to select optional fields with multiple joins

Tags: vb.net, linq

I currently have this linq statement..

```
Dim results = (From pb In db.ParcelBases
               Join l In db.LegalDescs On pb.lrsn Equals l.LRSN
               Join sh In db.SalesHists On pb.lrsn Equals sh.lrsn
               Where sh.sale_date >= dateFrom
               Where sh.sale_date <= dateTo
               Where sh.sale_amt >= psfldLow
               Where sh.sale_amt <= psfldHigh
               Select New With {
                 pb.lrsn,
                 pb.prop_street,
                 pb.owner1,
                 l.LEG_DESCRIPTION,
                 pb.parcel_id
               }).ToList
```

However, I have roughly 7 optional fields that I need to search as well. What is the best way to do this? Am I going to have to check if those fields are null and create a statement for each one of those checks? Or is there a way to do it within the statement itself? The ones currently in the statement are the required fields that are needed for the minimum selection.

Update: I'm trying to accomplish something like this..

```
Dim results = (From pb In db.ParcelBases
               Join l In db.LegalDescs On pb.lrsn Equals l.LRSN
               Join sh In db.SalesHists On pb.lrsn Equals sh.lrsn
               Where sh.sale_date >= dateFrom 'required field
               Where sh.sale_date <= dateTo   'required field
               Where sh.sale_amt >= psfldLow  'required field
               Where sh.sale_amt <= psfldHigh 'required field
               Where pb.propcity = tbPropCity 'optional field-could be null
               Where pb.proptype = tbPropType 'optional field-could be null
               Select New With {
                 pb.lrsn,
                 pb.prop_street,
                 pb.owner1,
                 l.LEG_DESCRIPTION,
                 pb.parcel_id
               }).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an `Or` statement, like:

```
Dim results = (From pb In db.ParcelBases
               Join l In db.LegalDescs On pb.lrsn Equals l.LRSN
               Join sh In db.SalesHists On pb.lrsn Equals sh.lrsn
               Where (sh.sale_date >= dateFrom
               And (sh.sale_date <= dateTo) 
               And (sh.sale_amt >= psfldLow)
               And (sh.sale_amt <= psfldHigh) 
Or (tbPropCity <> Nothing and  pb.propcity = tbPropCity) ' check for nulls here if necessary or something else Or... etc. )
                   Select New With {
                     pb.lrsn,
                     pb.prop_street,
                     pb.owner1,
                     l.LEG_DESCRIPTION,
                     pb.parcel_id
                   }).ToList
```

At least it sounds what you are looking for

Comment: Eh, sorta. I have 7 more text boxes that I have to query as well, but they are optional. The ones in the statement are the required fields. I'll update my question a bit.

Comment: I have updated my question a bit to include two of the optional fields.

Comment: well still it stands it is a combination of And's and Or's

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure. In this the And or Or doesn't exist.. that's why I went with the multiple Where's.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a view model with optional fields.

```
public class Thing {
    public type lrsn {get;set;}
    public type prop_street {get;set;}
    public type owner1 {get;set;}
    public type LEG_DESCRIPTION {get;set;}
    public type? propcity {get;set;}
    public type? proptype {get;set;}

    public Thing(
         type lrsn,
         type prop_street,
         type owner1,
         type LEG_DESCRIPTION,
         type? propcity = null,
         type? proptype = null)
    {
         this.lrsn = lrsn;
         this.prop_street = prop_street;
         this.owner1 = owner1;
         this.LEG_DESCRIPTION;
         this.propcity = propcity;
         this.proptype = proptype;
    }
}
```

And then wherever your code was:

```
using namespace.Thing;

Dim results = (From pb In db.ParcelBases
           Join l In db.LegalDescs On pb.lrsn Equals l.LRSN
           Join sh In db.SalesHists On pb.lrsn Equals sh.lrsn
           Where sh.sale_date >= dateFrom
           Where sh.sale_date <= dateTo
           Where sh.sale_amt >= psfldLow
           Where sh.sale_amt <= psfldHigh
           Select New Thing(
             pb.lrsn,
             pb.prop_street,
             pb.owner1,
             l.LEG_DESCRIPTION,
             pb.parcel_id
           )).ToList
```